# get unserialize single value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am sending the data from $_post['diet_info'] in the form array. the following is the form fields in which data is sending.

```
<table>
<tr><td></td><td align="center">Breakfast</td><td align="center">Snack1</td><td align="center">Lunch</td><td align="center">Snack2</td><td align="center">Dinner</td></tr>
<tr><td>Monday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['mon_breakfast']" id="mon_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['mon_snack1']" id="mon_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['mon_lunch']" id="mon_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['mon_snack2']" id="mon_snack2"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['mon_dinner']" id="mon_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tuseday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['tuse_breakfast']" id="tuse_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['tuse_snack1']" id="tuse_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['tuse_lunch']" id="tuse_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['tuse_snack2']" id="tuse_snack2"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['tuse_dinner']" id="tuse_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Wednesday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['wed_breakfast']" id="wed_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['thu_snack1']" id="thu_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['wed_lunch']" id="wed_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['wed_snack2']" id="mon_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['wed_dinner']" id="wed_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Thursday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['thu_breakfast']" id="thu_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['thu_snack1']" id="thu_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['thu_lunch']" id="thu_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['thu_snack2']" id="thu_snack2"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['thu_dinner']" id="thu_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Friday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['fri_breakfast']" id="fri_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['fri_snack1']" id="fri_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['fri_lunch']" id="fri_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['fri_snack2']" id="fri_snack2"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['fri_dinner']" id="fri_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Saturday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sat_breakfast']" id="sat_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sat_snack1']" id="sat_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sat_lunch']" id="sat_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sat_snack2']" id="sat_snack2"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sat_dinner']" id="sat_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sunday</td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sun_breakfast']" id="sun_breakfast"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sun_snack1']" id="sun_snack1"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sun_lunch']" id="sun_lunch"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sun_snack2']" id="sun_snack2"></textarea></td><td><textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['sun_dinner']" id="sun_dinner"></textarea></td></tr>
```

after receiving the request i searlaized it as accordingly

```
$new = serialize($_POST['diet_info']);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'diet_info', $new);
```

Now i need single value by the help of key after unserialized. Here is my code

```
<?php $diet_info = unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'diet_info', true) ); ?>
<textarea class="diet_textarea" name="diet_info['mon_breakfast']" id="mon_breakfast"><?php echo $diet_info['mon_breakfast'];?></textarea>
```

by using this method i can't able to get value can any one help me?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: i am not able to get the value

Comment: `var_dump($diet_info)`

Comment: i used print_r($diet_info) the array is printing perfectly fine

Comment: "the array is printing perfectly fine", then some went wrong, because print_r shows some like: Array ( [foo] =>bar)  without the ' in [] , maybe $diet_info["'mon_breakfast'"] works, single in double quotes

Comment: i have tried it but it's not working for me

Comment: try print_r(array_keys($diet_info)); after unserialize( get_post...  to see what keys are really in the array

Comment: Kindly post complete array. Thanks.

Comment: i have updated the question i think it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name="diet_info['thu_breakfast']"
```

removeall ' (singlecode) in your HTML-code,like

```
name="diet_info[thu_breakfast]"
```

That should fix it.

Comment: didn't saw in the textarea line;)

Comment: in html array look like:  arr[arg1]

Comment: Great it's working perfectly i am confused from last two hours thanks for your help.